Purpose of KBDHID "WorkNicely" Parameter
What is HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\KBDHID\Parameters\WorkNicely Parameter? What does this parameter control and what is its purpose? Is it related to the user-generated BSOD/crash-control function?
There doesn't seem to be any information about this on the Internet, the only search results that include it are of registry dumps of the key which of course say nothing about what it actually does.
It seems to default to 0 which from its name seems like the opposite of what would be desirable. My best guess is that instead of immediately performing a raw BSOD, it tries to avoid data-corruption by closing file and device handles before initiating the crash.
Does anyone have any idea or knowledge of what this key does?
